# How to set up non endorsing peers in Hyperledger Fabric 2.2.3

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I installed two peers in two different organizations Org1MSP and Org2MSP and installed chaincode on all 4 peers. I did not set signing policy explicitly as it takes "Majority" as implicit signing policy. I am able to get information from all the peers when executed query. Later I added two new peers to each organization and made both of them to join the channel and installed chaincode on both of them. I did not execute approveformyorg now as it was already done in the previous step.

I am using Hyperledger Fabric 2.2.3 version.

Later when I executed

```
"discover --configFile discovery-conf.yaml endorsers --channel
channelone --server peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --chaincode basic"
```

I am getting details of all 6 peers of both the organizations. How do I configure non endorsing peers in my set up. I want to have atleast one non endorsing peer in each organization.

Answer (score 0):

Every peer that has joined a channel is a committer on that channel.
If the peer has chaincode installed, it can act as an endorser.
If clients Invoke the installed chaincode on the peer, then it will act as an endorser.

Comment: In my case all peers joined the channel hence they are committers. Out of 6, I installed chaincode on 4 nodes hence they are endorsers as per your reply above. What about the remaining 2 peers in which I did not install chaincode. When I execute peer channel query command on those two peers I am getting "Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500 message:"make sure the chaincode basic has been successfully defined on channel channelone and try again: chaincode definition for 'basic' exists, but chaincode is not installed".

Comment: So, unless I install chaincode I cannot query a peer and as a result of installing chaincode on a peer it is becoming endorsing peer. Because of this scenario it turns out to be that all peers are both endorsers as well as committers in Hyper Ledger Fabric network.

Comment: You need to install chaincode on the peer to perform queries. 
Every peer node in a channel is a committing peer.Every peer with a smart contract can be an endorsing peer . An endorsement policy for a smart contract identifies the organizations whose peer should digitally sign a generated transaction before it can be accepted onto a committing peer’s copy of the ledger.